# Send an event up multiple parents to trigger a function Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a main-page.componenent.ts like so...

```
<app-page-component></app-page-component>
```

and then inside my app-page component I have another nested component like so..

```
<nested-compoennt></nested-component>
```

so basically my app looks like this

```
<app-main-component> // where the function is
    <app-page-component>
       <nested-component></nested-component> // where the button is
    </app-page-component>
</app-main-component>
```

now I have a button in my nested-component and I want that to trigger a function on the top parent component.. now I know if I was passing an event to the most direct parent I could use an event emitter but Im not sure if that will work in this case.. so my question is how can I 'bubble' up an event so it hits the most parent container and triggers and event?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

The first option, you can have each component have an output that broadcasts the event up. This can get unweildly pretty quickly, especially if it is deeply nested.

The second option, you can use a shared service to send and receive messages. Essentially your component that has the button would call a method on your service that broadcasts out the event and your parent component would use the service to subscribe to these events that are broadcast out and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of cases and little bit hard to understand what your case is.

In my view,
There would be 2 opstions.

1. grandparent <=> parent <=> children : event emitter
   (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service)
2. using service : define service and call children components to set data or make events, and grandparent subscribe the value changes or event subscribe.

I hope this would be helpful :)